# Temporary Variable in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

I have a form that auto-completes from a database containing 2000+ and growing names. This works fine, but there's an annoying lag between when the user types and when the list is returned. I want to store the data temporarily during the lifetime of the page to speed things up.

Using static variables seems to work, but I'm scared of the auto-complete variable becoming out of date. Is there something else I could use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`Caching.Cache`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cache.aspx) class to hold the values - when you [insert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/41ttybaf) to the cache, you can set the item to expire using a `TimeSpan`, or depending on the version of SQL Server, you could use [`SqlDependency`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldependency.aspx) directly with it to track changes in the DB.

Comment: Misclick didn't mean to. Was trying to remove my upvote... The flaw in caching with timespan it would have been better to use a SQLdependency

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm going through an API and don't have direct access to the SQL server. The caching class looks to be what I needed though. Thanks!

Comment: @ggonsalv - Good point. Didn't consider `SqlDependency`. Thanks. Answer updated.